# \textvdots with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, ellipsis

Uncommenting any of the two commented lines in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
%\textvdots%%% fails with "Command \textvdots unavailable in encoding T1."
%\newcommand{\textvdots}{\(\vdots\)}%%% fails with "Command \textvdots already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual."
\end{document}
```

and feeding the results to [pdf|xe|lua]latex yields a compilation error.

You can also use NewTX fonts or TeX Gyre Termes; the outcome is the same.

So ***why*** is there a reasonable command that you can neither use nor define by standard LaTeX `\newcommand`?   (Surely you can construct your own vertical ellipsis via `\def\textvdots{…}` or `\DeclareRobustCommand{\textvdots}{…}`, but that's not my question. )

Answer (score 1):

hyperref defines the command for the encoding needed in the bookmarks (PU). If you want to define it too you can either break hyperref's definition by using `\def` or `\renewcommand` or you can add one (or more) parallel definitions for the encodings you intend to use.

This is done with \DeclareTextCommand which takes as second argument the encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareTextCommand\textvdots{T1}{\vdots}

\begin{document}
\textvdots
\end{document}
```

Comment: First, thanks. Second, I'm afraid this answers the question "how to define the vertical ellipsis" properly but not the "why" in the original post. Third, what do you do if your preamble contains `\usepackage[T2A,T1,T3]{fontenc}` (i.e., not a simple `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`)?

Comment: I added some explanation.

Comment: Thx! So if you have several encodings, say, T2A, T1, and T3, do you have to say something like `\DeclareTextCommand\textvdots{T2A}{\vdots}
\DeclareTextCommand\textvdots{T3}{\vdots}
\DeclareTextCommand\textvdots{T1}{\vdots}`?

Comment: yes, or you break hyperref and handle the bookmarks yourself.

Comment: Thx! And which encoding do you use for lualatex? Saying `\DeclareTextCommand\textvdots{TU}{\vdots}` results in empty output instead of ⋮.  My source code for lualatex: https://pastebin.com/nVn54aNa .

Comment: unicode-math redefines \vdots. That is unrelated to your question here, so ask a new question.